# In C# what is perception?

Tags: c#

In one of the job interview  some one asked me, In C# what is perception? And i don't know what he mean to say until now. Can some one brief it ?

Comment: Perception? Do you mean *exception*?

Comment: Thats it, is it all he asked , something more to add to the context ? may be he was asking about perception of C# for x type of project

Comment: Perception in C# is the same thing as `Perception` is in F#, Java, C++ and Bash (Shell) Script... And it is the ability of the coder to see (percept) what is wrong in a statement. I hope you dont mean "exception", and if you do... damn... xD

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting this question. Someone heard an unfamiliar term and asks for clarification - what's wrong with it?

Comment: Tou misheard. I would guess it was _Reflection_, or maybe _Exceptions_. Both are easy to google.

Comment: @Henk Either that or the person holding the interview didn't really know what he was talking about ;)

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as `perception` in C#.

This word does not exist in C# 4.0 spec (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) at all.

Probably you've misunderstood a different word.